# Passing and using variable number of arguments to function in C

Tags: c

I don't understand why this doesn't print out "this is a test 42" like I'm expecting it to?

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdarg.h>
  3 
  4 #define ME(x)   blah x
  5 
  6 void blah(const char *fmt, ...)
  7 {
  8         va_list arg;
  9 
 10         va_start(arg, fmt);
 11         printf(fmt, arg);
 12         va_end(arg);
 13 }
 14 
 15 int main()
 16 {
 17         ME(("this is a test %d\n", 42));
 18 
 19         return 0;
 20 }
```

Instead it's something like this:

```
$ gcc blah.c
$ ./a.out
this is a test 1606416656
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to call vprintf() instead of printf().

Comment: Thank you very much! In the linux kernel, I'm assuming there is also vprintk?

Comment: Seems so, googling for "kernel vprintk" found this:
http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0407.3/1688.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use va_arg to get the actual argument value.  Va_start is only an initialization of the arg variable.  Arg is actualy a pointer to the value on the stack, it's not the valut itself.

The following line gets the actual value:

```
int myvalue = va_arg(arg,int);
```

Notice that I get an int and not a short, since short's are automatically promoted to int by the C compiler.

**EDIT:** Uli's answer is also correct.  If you want to pass multiple values to printf, you should call vprintf instead of printf (and then calling va_arg is not needed, since in this case you don't know the exact types of the arguments).