# Do C functions support an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: c

PHP has a `func_get_args()` for getting all function arguments, and JavaScript has the `functions` object.

I've written a very simple `max()` in C

```
int max(int a, int b) {
    
    if (a > b) {
        return a;   
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure in most languages you can supply any number of arguments to their `max()` (or equivalent) built in. Can you do this in C?

I thought this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615806/passing-and-using-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function-in-c) may have been what I wanted, but I don't think it is.

Please keep in mind I'm still learning too. :)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write a variable-arguments function that takes the number of arguments, for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int sum(int numArgs, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numArgs);

    int ret = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++i)
    {
        ret += va_arg(args, int);
    }    

    va_end(args);

    return ret;
}    

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sum(4,  1,3,3,7)); /* prints 14 */
}
```

The function assumes that each variable argument is an integer (see `va_arg` call).

Comment: That's rather strange implementation of `max`... ;)

Comment: Thanks, but `max()` is meant to return the largest number, not add them up :P

Comment: Corrected that ^^. Implementing `max` should be pretty straightforward ;)

Comment: Do I *have* to tell the function how many arguments I'm sending? `printf()` doesn't seem to want to know, but I guess it could count all the format characters in the first argument to find out.

Comment: That's right, printf just looks at the number of format codes. Put in too many format codes and it's likely to misbehave in interesting ways.

Comment: @AndiDog: You've still left it as a call to `max` instead of `sum` in the `printf` statement.

Comment: @alex: Yes, you have to. But you could work around that using macros. For example, one could use a sentinel value INT_MIN that stops the function from going through the arguments. Then you could define a variadic macro (note that not all compilers support that) `#define max(...) maxfunction(__VA_ARGS__, INT_MIN)`.

Comment: @AndiDog: I'd expect `max(INT_MIN, 0)` to be well-defined. I can't really see how to safely pass a sentinel.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, C has the concept of variadic functions, which is similar to the way `printf()` allows a variable number of arguments.

A maximum function would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>

static int myMax (int quant, ...) {
    va_list vlst;
    int i;
    int num;
    int max = INT_MIN;

    va_start (vlst, quant);

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            max = va_arg (vlst, int);
        } else {
            num = va_arg (vlst, int);
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
    va_end (vlst);
    return max;
}

int main (void) {
    printf ("Maximum is %d\n", myMax (5, 97, 5, 22, 5, 6));
    printf ("Maximum is %d\n", myMax (0));
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Maximum is 97
Maximum is -2147483648
```

Note the use of the `quant` variable. There are generally two ways to indicate the end of your arguments, either a count up front (the `5`) or a sentinel value at the back.

An example of the latter would be a list of pointers, passing `NULL` as the last. Since this `max` function needs to be able to handle the entire range of integers, a sentinel solution is not viable.

The `printf` function uses the former approach but slightly differently. It doesn't have a specific *count*, rather it uses the `%` fields in the format string to figure out the other arguments.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, this are two questions. First of all C99 only requires that a C implementation may handle at least:

- 127 parameters in one function
  definition
- 127 arguments in one function call

Now, to your real question, yes there are so-called variadic functions and macros in C99. The syntax for the declaration is with `...` in the argument list. The implementation of variadic functions goes with macros from the `stdarg.h` header file.

Answer (score 2):

here is a link to site that shows an example of using varargs in c [Writing a ``varargs'' Function](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html)

You can use the va_args function to retrieve the optional arguments you pass to a function. And using this you can pass 0-n optional parameters. So you can support more then 2 arguments if you choose

Comment: Note that unlike PHP and Javascript, with C varargs your function needs to be able to work out from the values of the non-variable args, what the types and number of the varargs are (or I guess you could work out the type of the first vararg from the non-var args, then the type of the second from the value of the first and so on). So you will not get a vararg `max` function that looks quite how you want it to look - this is a limitation of the C language.

Comment: @Steve: You can work around this by wrapping the variadic function with a variadic macro that counts the arguments and passes the count as the first argument.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can declare a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) function in C. The most commonly used one is probably `printf`, which has a declaration that looks like the following

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

The `...` is how it declares that it accepts a variable number of arguments.

To access those argument it can uses `va_start`, `va_arg` and the like which are typically macros defined in `stdarg.h`. See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg)

It is probably also worth noting that you can often "confuse" such a function. For example the following call to `printf` will print whatever happens to be on the top of the stack when it is called. In reality this is probably the saved stack base pointer.

```
printf("%d");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to pass in an array, like `main()`. for example:

`int myfunc(type* argarray, int argcount);`

Answer (score 0):

`C` can have functions receive an arbitrary number of parameters.

You already know one: `printf()`

```
printf("Hello World\n");
printf("%s\n", "Hello World");
printf("%d + %d is %d\n", 2, 2, 2+2);
```

There is no `max` function which accepts an arbitrary number of parameters, but it's a good exercise for you to write your own.

Use `<stdarg.h>` and the `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` identifiers defined in that header.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdarg.3.html